# Reset changed HTML text to default

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have multiple paragraphs and labels:

```
<p id="test">some text</p>
```

that i'm changing via javascript:

```
document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = "changed text";
```

Now I want to reset ***test*** back to its original text value -> "some text"

How do I achieve this, without declaring extra variables like this:

```
var default_text = document.getElementById("test").text;
```

Is there something similar to form data's reset(); method?

Comment: No `reset` method available for this, only store original text to some variable

Comment: ... or alternatively  hide the original, and create new elements for new texts. Then when resetting, remove the latter element, and show the original.

Comment: Don't quote me on this, but if you really don't want to save it inside a variable save it under a `data-original-text` attribute in the element itself.

Comment: feels a bit fishy to declare a extra variable for stuff that i already have inside my html. but if theres no other way....

Comment: @tipsfedora yeah, but you'd have to store it somewhere :o)